# c# WebBrowser При наведении нажатие левой кнопки мышки

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Как сделать так чтобы при наведении на WebBrowser1 **Нажималось левая кнопка мышки?**

На **Button** есть **event MouseHover**:

```
private void button2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Но на **WebBrowser1**'е не нашол **MouseHover**...

Answer (score 1):

Компонент `WebBrowser` является оболочкой над нативным браузером. Поэтому у него нет привычных событий из мира управляемых контролов.

Одним из способов является использование таймера:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var point = PointToClient(MousePosition);

    if (webBrowser.ClientRectangle.Contains(point))
    {
        // мышь над браузером
    }
}
```

Comment: Да это я понял   // мышь над браузером но как мне же заставить нажать левую кнопки мышки когда мышь над браузером?

Comment: @Sauron - А какое содержимое в браузере в этот момент? Если там html, то можно получить `HtmlElement` и работать с ним. Если там Flash или ещё что, - то, видимо, только через WinAPI пытаться слать сообщения (могу ошибаться).